# Python Telnetlib validating login not working

Tags: python, authentication, networking, devops, telnetlib

I'm writing a code in Python3 that login into routers and switches, with different user/password (try next user if the previous is wrong) and different vendors (cisco, huawei, juniper, etc), some use SSH and others use Telnet.

With SSH (paramiko), I'm able to try users login on differents vendors.
But Telnet (telnetlib), does not give any login error or exception, so I can't validate and try other user/pass.

Anybody has any idea, how can I try that?

I'm stucked here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time, datetime, telnetlib

now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d__%H%M%S")

# host ip address
ip = '127.0.0.1'
# commands to execute after login, that I'll save the output
comando1 = "disable clipaging"
comando2 = "show configuration"
comando3 = "exit"
login_info = {"user1":"pass1","user2":["pass1","pass2","pass3"]}
lista_login_info = []
valida_login = False
i = 0
cont =0


# this FOR loop read my dict and make a list with all combinations
lista_login_info = []
i = 0
for username in login_info:
    # DEFINE O TIPO DA VARIÁVEL, SE FOR 
    type_username_var = type(login_info[username])
    # TESTA LOGIN RADIUS (login que tem apenas 1 entrada de senha)
    if type_username_var is str:
        password = login_info[username]
        lista_login_info.append([username,password])
        # print ("User: {}\nPass: {}".format(username, password))
        i+=1
    # TESTA LOGINs LOCAIS (login local com várias senhas, user local com as demais senhas que estão num array)
    else:
        for password in login_info[username]:
            # print ("User: {}\nPass: {}".format(username, password))
            lista_login_info.append([username,password])
            i+=1

# I take  this line from an output, so I tryed to read it
login_incorreto = ["Login incorrect"]
# login_incorreto = "\rLogin incorrect\r\n"

valida_login = False
cont = 0

# the prints with the word AQUI, I'm using just to find in which part of the code is executing

output = []
while valida_login == False:
    cont +=1
    print("AQUI1")
    try:
        print("AQUI2")
        for login_data in lista_login_info:
            print("AQUI3")
            now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d__%H%M%S")
            print ("-"*70)
            print ("\nHost: {} - username: {} - Password: {}\n".format(ip,login_data[0],login_data[1]))
            tn = telnetlib.Telnet(ip,23,15)
            print("AQUI4")
            tn.set_debuglevel(1) # I enabled a debug to see whats is going wrong
            time.sleep(1)
            tn.read_until('login: '.encode('utf-8'))
            time.sleep(1)
            tn.write(("{}\n").format(login_data[0]).encode('ascii'))
            print("AQUI5")
            tn.read_until("password:".encode('utf-8'))
            tn.write(('{}\n'.format(login_data[1]).encode('ascii')))
            print("AQUI6")
            time.sleep(4)

            readoutput = tn.read_all().decode('ascii')
            for line in readoutput:
                if login_incorreto in line:
                    print (login_incorreto)
                else:
                    tn.write("{}\n".format(comando1).encode('ascii'))
                    tn.write("{}\n".format(comando2).encode('ascii'))
                    tn.write("{}\n".format(comando3).encode('ascii'))
                    tn.close()

            try:
                print("AQUI7")
                # readoutput = tn.read_all().decode('ascii')
                readoutput = readoutput.split('\n')
                print("AQUI8")
                for linha in readoutput:
                    linha = linha.rstrip('\r')
                    linha = linha.strip('\r')
                    output.append([linha])
                # print (output)

                # print("AQUI9")
                print("AQUI10")
                # this for and if is to save in a file my output
                for var in output:
                    if var == login_incorreto:
                        print (login_incorreto)
                        print("AQUI11")
                        break
                        # tn.close()
                    else:
                        # saveoutput = open("bkp_telnet__{}_{}__{}__{}.txt".format(ip,now,login_data[0],login_data[1]), "w")
                        print("AQUI12")
                        # for linhas in readoutput:
                        #   saveoutput.write(linhas)
                        #   saveoutput.write("\n")
                        #   print("AQUI13")
                        #   valida_login = True
                        # saveoutput.close()

                print (valida_login)
                if valida_login == True:
                    print("AQUI14")
                    break
            except:
                if cont == 5:
                    print ('\n\n\n')
                    print ('ENTROU EM LOOP')
                    valida_login = True
                    break
    except EOFError as error:
        print ("Erro: {}".format(error))
        print("AQUI15")
        valida_login = False
    except Exception as exception:
        print("AQUI16")
        print ("Exception: {}".format(exception))
        if exception:
            break
        # valida_login = False
```

**that's an output exemple error:**

```
disable clipaging

show configuration

exit


Login incorrect



login: disable clipaging


password: 





Login incorrect



login: exit


password: Login timed out!
```

**output wit debug on:**

```
AQUI1
AQUI2
AQUI3
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Host: 127.0.0.1 - username: user1 - Password: pass1

AQUI4
Telnet(127.0.0.1,23): recv b'\xff\xfb\x03\xff\xfb\x01\xff\xfd\x1f\xff\xfd\x18\r\ntelnet session telnet0 on /dev/ptyb0'
Telnet(127.0.0.1,23): IAC WILL 3
Telnet(127.0.0.1,23): IAC WILL 1
Telnet(127.0.0.1,23): IAC DO 31
Telnet(127.0.0.1,23): IAC DO 24
Telnet(127.0.0.1,23): recv b'\r\n\r\n\r\nSystem is in trial for 30 day(s) and this wi'
Telnet(127.0.0.1,23): recv b'll expire in 0 day(s)\r\nlogin: '
Telnet(127.0.0.1,23): send b'user1\n'
AQUI5
Telnet(127.0.0.1,23): recv b'u'
Telnet(127.0.0.1,23): recv b'ser1\r\n\rpassword: '
Telnet(127.0.0.1,23): send b'pass1\n'
AQUI6
Telnet(127.0.0.1,23): recv b'\r\n\r\r\n'
Telnet(127.0.0.1,23): recv b'\rLogin incorrect\r\n\r\nSystem is in trial for 30 day('
Telnet(127.0.0.1,23): recv b's) and this will expire in 0 day(s)\r\n'
Telnet(127.0.0.1,23): recv b'login: '
AQUI16
Exception: timed out
[Finished in 29.9s]
```

Comment: Have you tried using `expect` for this? it might make the task easier.

Comment: Also, make sure none of the devices you're trying this on will lock out an account after a certain number of failed attempts.

Comment: I didn't try expect, I'll search that, thanks, and almost every device, default login attempts are 3